# Generate or find a shortest text given list of words

Tags: algorithm, search, nlp

Let's say I have a list of 1000+ words and I would like to generate a text that includes these words from the list. I would like to use as few extra words outside of the list as possible. How would one tackle such a problem? Or alternatively, is there a way to efficiently search for a smaller portion of text containing these words the most, given some larger text (millions of words)? Basically, the resulting text from the search should be optimized to be shortest but to contain all the words from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you'd like the text to be generated, so I'll attempt to answer the second question:

> Is there a way to efficiently search for a smaller portion of text containing these words the most, given some larger text (millions of words)? Basically, the resulting text from the search should be optimized to be shortest but to contain all the words from the list.

This is obviously a computationally demanding endeavour so I'll assume you are alright with spending like a gig of RAM on this and some time (but maybe not too long). Since you are looking for the shortest continuous text which satisfies some condition, one can conclude the following:

1. If the text satisfies the condition, you want to shorten it.
2. If it doesn't, you want to make it longer so that hopefully it will start satisfying the condition.

Now, when it comes to the condition, it is whatever predicate that will say whether the continuous section of the text is "good enough" or not, based on some relatively simple statistics. For instance, the predicate could check if some cumulative index based on what ratio of the words from your list are included in the section, modified by the number of words from outside the list, is greater than some expected value.

What my mind races to when I see something like this is the sliding window technique, described in [this article](https://medium.com/outco/how-to-solve-sliding-window-problems-28d67601a66). I do not know if this is a good article, I did not take the time to read it, but scanning through it seems to be decent. It's also known as the [caterpillar method](https://codility.com/media/train/13-CaterpillarMethod.pdf), which is a particularly common name for it in Poland.

Basically, you have two pointers, a left pointer and a right pointer. In the case of looking for the shortest continuous fragment of a larger text, such that the fragment satisfies a condition and given that if a condition is met for a fragment, then it is met for a larger fragment containing the previous fragment, you advance the right pointer forward as long as the condition is unmet, and then once it is met, you advance the left pointer, until the condition isn't met. This repeats until either or both pointers reach the end of the text.

This is a neat technique, which allows you to iterate over the whole text exactly once, linearly. It is clearly desirable in your case to have an algorithm linear with respect to the length of the text.

Now, we have to consider the statistics you will be collecting. You will probably want to know how many words from the list, and how many words from outside of the list are present in a continuous fragment. An extra condition for these statistics is that they will need to be relatively easily modifiable (preferably in constant time, but that will be hard to achieve) every time one of the pointers advances.

In order to keep track of the words, we will use a hashmap of ordered sets of indeces. In Java these data structures are called `HashMap` and `TreeSet`, in C++ they're `unordered_map` and `set`. The keys to the hashmap will be strings representing words. The values will be sets of indices of where the words appear in the text. Note that lookup in a hashmap is linear relative to the length of the key, so we can assume constant as most words are like <10 characters long, and checking how many values in a set there are between two given values is logarithmic relative to the size of the set. So getting the number of times a word appears in a fragment of the text is easy and fast. Keeping track of whether a word exists in the given list or not can also be achieved with a hashmap (or a hashset).

So let's get back to the statistics. Say you want to keep track of the number of words from inside and from outside your list in a given fragment. This can be achieved very simply:

1. Every time you add a word to the fragment by advancing its right end, you check if it appears in the list in constant time and if so, you add one to the "good words" number, and otherwise, you add one to the "bad words" number.
2. Every time you remove a word from the fragment by advancing the left end, you do the same but you decrement the counters instead.

Now if you want to track how many ***unique*** words from inside and from outside the list there are in the fragment, every time you will need to check the number of times a given word exists in the fragment. We established earlier that this can be done logarithmically relative to the length of the fragment, so now the trick is simple. You only modify the counters if the number of appearances of a word in the fragment either

1. rose from 0 to 1 when advancing the right pointer, or
2. fell from 1 to 0 when advancing the left pointer.

Otherwise, you ignore the word, not changing the counters.

Additional memory optimisations include removing indices from the sets of indices when they are out of scope of the fragment and removing hashmap entries from the hashmap if a set of indices becomes empty.

It is now up to you to perhaps find a better heuristic, some other statistical values which you can easily track whatever it is you intend to check in your predicate. Although it is important that whenever a fragment meets your condition, a bigger fragment must meet it too.

In the case described above you could keep track of all the fragments which had at least... I don't know... 90% of the words from your list and from those choose the shortest one or the one with the fewest foreign words.